# How to add new items in our project dynamically from our program?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there is any method to add new items or existing items in our project from our program?

For example:
if i need to add example.aspx page from my program then how to add it?? And it should save in solution explorer.

Comment: dont do that.

if you work with source controll - it WILL cause a problem. since you adding files via filesystem and not from the solution as it should.

Answer (score 0):

normally you would use a CMS-alike workflow, where you can set up a Master Layout and then make an Administrative way to add content to each part of the page you would want.

In a simple way, you can just easily create pages using 2 textboxes and a submit button:

```
<input type="text" id="txtFileName" />
<textarea id="txtContent" rows="80" cols="12"></textarea>
<input type="submit" id="btnSave" value="Save File" />
```

and have your code to create a new text file with the passed contents like:

```
// create a writer and open the file
using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(
                                 txtFileName.Text, 
                                 false, 
                                 System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
{
    // write the content
    tw.Write(txtContent.Text);

    // close the stream
    tw.Close();
}
```

You can show a list of all files and read them the same way, so you can edit them...

**Now**, in ASP.NET, this might not work properly as the server will need to compile again and for that you will need to also change the project file, but you can run a local script issuing the compile line and that will re-compile everything for you.

Give it a try, and when you come up with some stopper, let us know, we might give you a hand on that...